# Java - Callable Out of memory solution?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, callable

Hi Guys can you help me about the error that I've encountered on my Java program. I do the Callable implementation with a loop, Basically I need to send a request to another webservice and I will be collecting the response ID. Based on my testing, my aim to process it asynchronously is working using the below implementation. One time I try to run again my program then I got this kind of error "**Error 500: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to create a thread: retVal -1073741830, errno 11**". What I did is I just restarted the server then it becomes ok.

So I want to know if there is something wrong with my implementation? like is there any additional line of code that I need to add or remove just to prevent again to experience those kind of error? I only experience it once. Hope you could help me

```
        //pccsSurvList is a list of details coming from the database.

        ExecutorService executorService = null;
        List<Callable<SyncFlagEntity>> lst = new ArrayList<Callable<SyncFlagEntity>>();
        
        if(pccsSurvList != null && pccsSurvList.size() > 0){
            executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pccsSurvList.size());
            for(PCCSSurveyInfoEntity user: pccsSurvList){

                NotifyEmailTransactionImpl emailTransact = new NotifyEmailTransactionImpl(user);
                lst.add(emailTransact);
                
            }
        }
        // returns a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete
        List<Future<SyncFlagEntity>> tasks = new ArrayList<Future<SyncFlagEntity>>();
        tasks = executorService.invokeAll(lst);

        executorService.shutdown();
```

Comment: `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pccsSurvList.size());` this could potentially create a large number of threads. Is that really intended?

Comment: Create a pool with a modest and fixed number of threads.

Comment: Hi @Thomas I did that so that the size that I'm creating a pool is fix on how many data need to process.. When I encounter the error, data that im about to process is about just around 38 details.

Comment: Hi @LouisWasserman what I was about to plan is I will be limiting the data that I will be getting from the database, like for example every invoke to my application I will be just retrieving 100-200 data/rows so that it will not process a large amount. do you think is just ok?

Comment: Too many threads running at once. Don’t do that.

Comment: Hi @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen what can you suggest? I need to send the request to another webservice in asynchronous way, then I will collect  all of their response before proceeding to next function.

Comment: Try to create a sensible number of threads (e.g. use `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`), submit all the tasks and wait for the futures to be completed (your code is already on a good way there). Also please check how much memory each task requires when it's idle (i.e. not being executed) and during execution. If memory requirements during execution are high you might have to reduce the number of threads that can execute in parallel, if the memory requirements for idle tasks are high already your process might just need more memory (and maybe a redesign to use less memory).

Comment: No.  Create a pool with a modest and fixed number of threads.  You can submit an unlimited amount of work to that pool, but your pool should have a small number of threads. 5, say, or 8.

Comment: Now I get it... Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to create a thread

This [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html) indicates that Java is out of memory.

Most likely the problem lies on this line ...

```
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pccsSurvList.size());
```

You are getting a lot of rows and there's no enough RAM for the JVM to create a thread for each one. Try logging the number of rows you get and see what's happening.

Comment: Hi @Arthur Klezovich that I've tried so far is 38 rows/data...  I think it adds up this is running on the Development server which there are a lot of application is running and the the specs server is much lower compared to the production... Is there any ideal size of the thread pool? Cause I'm planning to set it 100-200 per invoking my application..

Comment: It really makes no sense to create more threads than you have cores on your server. Look at the specs and use that amount.

Comment: Hi @Arthur Klezovich using my implementation above, should I need to use a Thread sleep? or my implementation is enough? by the way I already set the max Thread pool into 10.

Comment: You don't need sleep. Also, if this question has helped you, feel mark it as accepted, so its easier for other users to find and reuse it

Comment: Thank you @Arthur Klezovich

Answer (score 1):

I think you are running too many processes at once. You should try to set a limit and use a thread pool.

Maybe you can do something like:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pccsSurvList.size());
```

Then inside for loop you can do:

```
executor.submit(() -> emailTransact);
```

There is more here: https://www.baeldung.com/thread-pool-java-and-guava

Also take a look at reactive programming. Can be of more help in your case: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/RxJava/article.html